# Facebook Meta-tags not working properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta

I used the following:

```
meta property="og:image" content="https://splashyourcash.com/images/safee.jpg"
```

But facebook won't display the preview picture.
Looking forward to answers.

My page: https://splashyourcash.com

Comment: Are you sure to have a valid SSL Cert

Comment: You can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ for debug your pages

Answer (score 0):

It has the [image loaded ok](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsplashyourcash.com%2F), you do however have issues with a redirect on your `https` endpoint. Change to:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://splashyourcash.com/images/safee.jpg"/>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i edited it and i will check later because i think it will need some time to refresh